# Allocating Large array(9mb) of pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an Structure defined,

```
struct RadBuck {
    int size,
    int pos,
    int head
};
```

I wanted to create an array of this structure as `RadBuck *R[n]`. Everything is fine if `n` is small but the moment I reach 9 MB, I am getting segmentation fault. I have the same problem with `int a[n]` as well, but that I overcame, by `malloc`ing it, `int *a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));`
Since that is not possible for struct, I am confused.

Comment: It is possible that operating system gives limited stack space to your (all) program. Try to define your array static.

Comment: It's a classic stack overflow, and you can use `malloc`, just as you did for the `int` case.

Comment: Side note: `int *a = malloc(n*sizeof *a);` is shorter, less dangerous, more maintainable and more future-error-proof than `int *a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));`. Also, this is possible with structs too: `struct RadBuck *a = malloc(n*sizeof *a);` (Note: how you didn't repeat the type three times!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since that is not possible for struct, I am confused.

This surely **is** possible:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */

size_t n = 42;

struct RadBuck * p = malloc(n * sizeof(*p)); /* Here one also could do sizeof(struct RadBuck). */
if (NULL == p)
{
  perror("malloc() failed");
}
else
{
   /* Use p here as if it were an array. */
   p[0].size = 1; /* Access the 1st element via index. */

   (p + n - 1)->size = 2; /* Access the last element via the -> operator. */
}

free(p); /* Return the memory. */
```

---

Btw, it shall be:

```
struct RadBuck {
  int size;
  int pos;
  int head;
};
```

Use semicolons (`;`) to separate the structure's member declarations.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I tried what you said, but when I run a for loop, for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) { p[i]->size = 0} it says "error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘RadBuck’)"

Comment: Ya I used semicolons only, But I inplemented what you said, but while compiling it is showing the error I mention. "error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘RadBuck’)"

Comment: Is it sizeof(*p) or sizeof(RadBuck) ?

Comment: @user1518989: The first is the size of what `p` is pointing to, that is `struct RabBuck`, the latter is invalid, as there is no type `RadBuck` but only a type `struct RadBuck`. Please note, that this latter case is valid in C++, but ins't in C.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , it worked, however, I pass the variable p in another function, in that I am getting segmentation fault when do R[j]->size. and j = n/2. when I use R[j].size in the function, compilation error "error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union"

Comment: @user1518989: You might like to pose this as another question, providing the relevant code snippets. And take close look at the two possibilites how to access thr elements of an array allocated to a pointer in my example code. **Either** use  the `[]` operator **or** the `->` operator.

Comment: I am sorry, I passed the variable as R[] earlier, i overlooked it, now its working. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

When you use `malloc` or declare an array of size `n` the compiler try to allocate the needed space as contiguous in the memory. So, if you need a lot of memory, you should try to use a linked list instead of a vector. When you use a linked list your elements are sparse in memory and you should get a lot more.
If you want to use a linked list, you can rewrite your structure like this:

```
struct RadBuck {
    int size;
    int pos;
    int head;
    struct RadBuck *next;
};
```